# post_content getting cut off on blank space on $wpdb->update

Tags: plugins, wpdb

I am publishing the following post via xmlrpc

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered)"></head><body lang="EN-US">

<div class="WordSection1">

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal;text-autospace:none"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";
color:red'>This is a new document</span></b></p>

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal;text-autospace:none"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";
color:red'> </span></b></p>

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:
normal;text-autospace:none"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";
color:red'>Test Test Test</span></b></p>

</div>

</body></html>
```

With **define('SAVEQUERIES', true);** option in wp-config, the following MySQL query is produced:

```
(
    [0] => UPDATE `s_6_posts` SET `post_author` = 9, `post_date` = '2012-04-11 20:40:05', `post_date_gmt` = '2012-04-11 20:40:05', `post_content` = '\n\n\n<div class=\"WordSection1\">\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'>This is a new document</span></b></p>\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'> </span></b></p>\n\n<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal\"><b><span style=\'font-size:9.0pt;font-family:\"ArialNarrow\",\"sans-serif\";color:red\'>Test Test Test</span></b></p>\n\n</div>\n\n\n', `post_content_filtered` = '', `post_title` = '', `post_excerpt` = '', `post_status` = 'draft', `post_type` = 'post', `comment_status` = 'open', `ping_status` = 'open', `post_password` = '', `post_name` = '', `to_ping` = '', `pinged` = '', `post_modified` = '2012-04-11 20:40:05', `post_modified_gmt` = '2012-04-11 20:40:05', `post_parent` = 0, `menu_order` = 0, `guid` = 'https://qa.citivelocity.com/cvauthor/equitywire/?p=230' WHERE `ID` = 230
    [1] => 0.12744808197021
    [2] => wp_xmlrpc_server->serve_request, IXR_Server->IXR_Server, IXR_Server->serve, IXR_Server->call, wp_xmlrpc_server->mw_newPost, wp_insert_post
)
```

When I look at the database after the insert, the post_content column only contains

```
<div class="WordSection1">

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";color:red'>This is a new document</span></b></p>

<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal"><b><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";color:red'>
```

What is happening here is in

```
<span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"ArialNarrow","sans-serif";
    color:red'> </span>
```

block, everything after the space between `<span>` tag is cut off.  I manually ran the MySQL update statement from console and it inserts the data properly.

The collation for mysql is **utf8_general_ci** and the data does not contain any special characters.  I am at a lost as to why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried it without all the style markup?